M-BUS read out specific data blocks
I have multiple Inepro PRO380-Mb meters.
When I send command
0x10, 0x5B, 0x28, 0x83, 0x16

(address 40) i get full response from meter:
68 4b 4b 68 08 28 72 32 05 01 21 cd 25 01 02 51 00 00 00 0c 04 44 38 73 07 8c 10 04 73 14 89 04 8c 20 04 71 23 84 02 1c 04 44 38 73 07 9c 10 04 73 14 89 04 9c 20 04 71 23 84 02 2c 04 00 00 00 00 ac 10 04 00 00 00 00 ac 20 04 00 00 00 00 39 16.

That is 81 bytes of data.
I need only 3 data blocks data:
Total active energy    0C
Total active energy T1 8C10
Total active energy T2 8C20
M-bus register map from manual
If I get data I need it would be 40 bytes less data to send.
That is almost half data and can read multiple meters faster.
Is possible to command meter to send specific data at all?
If is any directions appreciated.
